# Очередность выполнения запросов к одной и той же таблице в MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, concurrency, транзакции

Если два пользователя сделают запрос к БД (напрмиер MySQL) к одной и той же таблице то запросы выполнятся по очереди?

Предположим у нас есть запрос `INSERT INTO instances (product_id) VALUES (1), (2),`... и так до`(1000)`

Предположим, что **пользователь1** обращается к БД и делает подобный запрос. И в то же время **пользователь2** делает ещё такой же запрос.

Как в БД будут выполняться эти запросы? Сначала выполнится весь запрос **пользователя1**, и только потом запрос **пользователя2**? Или же они будут выполняться одновременно?

Т.е. к примеру вставляется запись `INSERT INTO instances (product_id) VALUES (1)` **пользователя1**, потом запись `INSERT INTO instances (product_id) VALUES (1)` **пользователя2**, затем `INSERT INTO instances (product_id) VALUES (2)` **пользователя1** и т.д.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это зависит от уровня изоляции. Некоторые уровни позволяют иметь конкуренцию при выполнении DML утверждений относящихся к определенной таблице. При этом создаются замки на таблицу и на запись изменяемую этим утверждением. Как это происходит и какие механизмы используются базой данных для разрешения конфликтов лучше всего читать про [Блокировки и уровни изоляции транзакций InnoDB в MySQL](https://habr.com/post/238513/).